# How to stop a thread when activity is onPause?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So, there is a 5 second splash screen, but also a `skip` button at the bottom. This is how the splash runs.

```
public class Splash extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer splashsong;
Button skipsplash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle chiefsplash) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(chiefsplash);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    splashsong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.jingle);
    splashsong.start();
    skipsplash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipsplash);

    skipsplash.setOnClickListener(this);

    Thread splashtimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                switchactivity();
            }
        }
    };

    splashtimer.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View skipbutton) {
    switchactivity();
}

private void switchactivity() {
    Intent aftersplash = new Intent("com.example.testapp.MENU");
    startActivity(aftersplash);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    splashsong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Now I want there to be a choice to hit the `skip` button interrupting the 5 second wait, I guess not when a thread is running. So what happens after I click the `skip` button is: once 5 seconds passes from the creation of the `Activity`, it will open up the `Menu` `Activity`, no matter if I'm already there or somewhere else. Anyway to stop this?

Comment: What happens if you try `splashtimer.join()` ?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to implement that correctly, I'm new to Java. I get an error at this point when i try to put it in the switchactivity method. What does join do exactly?

Comment: @Axtn95 join will make one thread wait till the other is done. Here is a sample: http://pastebin.com/pfawvt0W

Comment: @Axtn95 so to make this simpler: if you do not press skip, you will wait for 5 seconds - which is ok. If you press skip on the other hand, you *do not* want to wait for 5 seconds. Am i right?

Comment: @Eugene Exactly! But it will pop up the Activity after 5 even when i'm already on it or on another activity in the app. So if i use join, and another thread is done, won't it still make the Activity pop up anyway?

Comment: @Axtn95 one more question. Are you *actually* sleeping there or doing something else. This is important because it depends how you will stop this: either a flag or interrupts.

Comment: @Eugene The splash screen is just a page with a picture and a song playing, and nothing else running or loading. Very simple app, used more as a TUT for me. BTW, you taking your time and answering is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a 5 sec sleep interval use small intervals in a loop and use a flag combination to skip thread gracefully anytime you want. Please try the modified code below.

```
public class Splash extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer splashsong;
Button skipsplash;
boolean skipWait = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle chiefsplash) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(chiefsplash);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

splashsong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.jingle);
splashsong.start();
skipsplash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipsplash);

skipsplash.setOnClickListener(this);

Thread splashtimer = new Thread() {
    int waitTime = 0;
    public void run() {
        while(waitTime < 5000 && !skipWait) {
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            waitTime += 500;
        }
        switchactivity();
    }
};

splashtimer.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View skipbutton) {
    skipWait = true;
}

private void switchactivity() {
Intent aftersplash = new Intent("com.example.testapp.MENU");
startActivity(aftersplash);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

super.onPause();
splashsong.release();
finish();
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked! I will study the code and remember the method you used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a handler

```
          Handler h = new Handler();
          h.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
```

call switchactivity() in the run method of runnable.
In onClick() remove all callbacks for that runnable

```
h.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead have a boolean isSplashRunning set to true, in the run have all operations in While(isSplashRunning ){} loop and when you want to stop the thread set 
isSplashRunning = false;
splashtimer.join();

Comment: from the code as it is right now, this is not going to help as he is sleeping for 5 seconds, once he started to sleep, setting a flag to true is not going to help, not until the sleep is over.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
splashtimer.stop();
```

and you should set the thread be a global object.

Comment: hmm i get that the deprecated, because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state. Should i just suppress it?

Comment: @Axtn95 NO! Never use the stop method. NEVER, it is deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Ok :), i didn't no worries.